# Как в GIT отменить merge, чтобы при этом сохранились последние коммиты?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

Создал локальную ветку для определенных задач. После завершения работы с ней сделал ее `merge` с `master`. После этого в `master` были сделаны три коммита уже для других задач. Как можно отменить `merge`, чтобы при этом сохранились эти три последние сделанные коммита после слияния?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два способа.

Первый - это создать коммит-откат. В истории появится ещё один коммит

```
git revert -m 1 <SHA of merge>
```

Способ рекомендованный, если изменения уже были запушены и на них что то важное завязано. Старый мердж коммит останется в истории плюс появится новый "коммит-откат"

Второй способ. Сделать ребейз

```
git rebase -i <SHA хеш коммита перед мержем>
```

В открытом редакторе (это скорее всего будет vim) удалить строку с ненужным коммитом (нажать <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> или перейти в режим редактирования и классически) и сохранится (<kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Возможно, будут конфликты, их нужно будет решать классически. ну и не забыть запушить.

Сами коммиты сохранятся (если будут конфликты, то они как бы не совсем сохранятся - все зависит от того, как сильно они были завязаны на изменения). Хеш коммитов поменяется, так что нельзя сказать, что они "останутся такими же".

Comment: Git уже давно не рекомендует использовать vim в качестве редактора. По крайней мере, под виндой.

Comment: Это проблемы винды. Если будет другой редактор, то скорее человек справится